# Converting a pair RDD JavaPairRDD<String, Double> to JavaPairRDD<Integer, Double>

Tags: apache-spark

Is there a way to create or convert a pair RDD from one type to another.

Example :

if we wanted to convert

`JavaPairRDD<String, Double>` to `JavaPairRDD<Integer, Double>`

here the task is just to change the type of the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can convert like below

```
JavaRDD<String> words = sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList("1","2"));

JavaPairRDD<String, Double> pairRDD = words.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s, 1.0));

JavaPairRDD<Integer, Double> pairRDD1 = pairRDD.mapToPair(f->new Tuple2<>(Integer.parseInt(f._1), 1.0));
```

Comment: I completely missed that _1 & _2 are the variables. Thank you.